# Dymola model not initializing with auxiliary variables turned off in output

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am trying to run a model in Dymola 2019 FD01 with auxiliary outputs turned off (to improve simulation speed). I've also set the flag:

```
Advanced.AutoRemoveAuxiliaries = true;
```

When I try to run the model, I get:

```
Error: Integrator failed to start model.
```

I am able to run the same model with Auxiliary Variable outputs turned on and the flag set to true.

I was wondering if someone else had this issue before and how to go about troubleshooting this problem.

The dymola user manual states this about the flag:

Advanced.AutoRemoveAuxiliaries - Removes code for auxiliary variables that neither influence the simulation state nor the outputs. This improves performance a bit. If the auxiliary code is used to assert correct behaviour or to generate external outputs, that code will not be run.

I am able to run some other models which have assert statements with the same settings (aux outputs off), so it seems like there is something else essential to the model removed during initialization.

I am trying to replicate the issue with a simple model but i have no idea where to even start.

Comment: A minimal example would help a lot. You can try to reduce the model by removing components and/or equations one-by-one. After every change, check if the error still exists. If yes, then remove additional components, if no then undo your changes and try with other components. Do that until you have isolated the problem.

Comment: I would assume that either the model has some necessary calls of external functions that are moved to the auxiliary section, and removing them causes some other external calls to fail, or there is some error in Dymola 2019 FD01 for this particular model. In the latter case you can contact support with the model - even if you haven't made it minimal.

Comment: Mr.Olsson, Thanks for the tip.There seem to be some external function calls pertaining to tables in the subsystem causing this issue. I'll see if I can remove them and report back if it solves the problem.

@marco I'll see if i can make a minimal example. I wont be able to make a stripped down example of the model i am working on because it requires a commercial license (Claytex).